# Is it possible to install different display drivers for each user account?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, package-management

Is it possible to install a display driver for one account (for example an NVIDIA display driver), and use another version for the second one?

Currently I'm trying to test between two methods of installing a framework. One uses deb package which installs all dependencies automatically.
In the other one however, I am the one who installs all needed dependencies.

Each method has its own pros and cons. My main problem is that if I use the first method, it will install a lot of dependencies, kernel headers, development packages, etc that may cause me issues. I do not know if I can be able to unroll all the changes the first method causes.

So I'm asking if creating a new user-account would give me the same capability so if one account gets ruined I would still be able to use the other account and be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in 1 system.

I would use virtualization for this. Install virtualbox or vmware player, 2 containers with Ubuntu and make backups of each as things go like you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not the case, virtualbox or vmware wont detect my GPU and let me install NVIDIA driver and CUDA toolkit. my main issue is that I must use my GPU and the only way I know, is to have a real ubuntu installed.

Comment: See Section 1.5, “Installing VirtualBox and extension packs” https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough You need "Intel Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O" (VT-d), or "AMD-Vi" for this ;)

Comment: Thanks alot @Rinzwind, Going to have a look at it and fingers crossed!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work! :(